# How do I start my code for this app (Final Grade Calculator in Swift)?

Tags: calculator, final

Instructions: Build an app that allows a user to enter their current grade in a class, their desired final grade in a class, the percent the exam is worth, and then calculates what the user needs to get on the final to achieve a desired grade.

As a user, I want to be able to enter my grade, enter my desired final grade, and enter the percent the exam is worth. As a user, I want to press a button - or use some other form of user interaction such as tap gesture - to calculate what I would need to get on my exam to reach the desired final grade.

I think I have an idea on how to start this project but I can't figure out the code and I can't seem to find anything online. I am a beginner so please keep that in mind when responding. Also please explain what each piece of code does for the app.